# Can't set tab bar items

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to set the items for my Tab Bar from the TabBarViewController.

However, once I set the items, here's the error I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Here's the code:

```
func imageWithImageSize(image:UIImage , newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage

    }



    let image1 = imageWithImageSize(UIImage(named: "Home.png")!, newSize: CGSizeMake(30, 30))

    let homeItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: image1, selectedImage: image1)


    let image2 = imageWithImageSize(UIImage(named: "Profile.png")!, newSize: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
    let profileItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: image2, selectedImage: image2)


    self.tabBar.setItems([homeItem,profileItem, homeItem, homeItem], animated: false)
```

Is there a solution around it?

Comment: error says  you can not modify tab bar item while you are using it

Comment: It seems like you are trying to modify an active tab bar item i.e. you are on tab1 and trying to modify that, for eg.

Comment: How should I do it instead? @PKT

Comment: where did you put your this code ? @dpstart

Answer (score 2):

you cant modify them directly instead you can do the following things.

1.Get the UITabBarController in which you want to add tabs.suppose you have tabBarController with name tabController.

2.Get all the viewController of tabController.

```
 guard var viewControllers = tabController.viewControllers else {
      return
    }
```

3.get your view controller. for ex. we take exampleVC.

4.create tabBarItem for exampleVC

```
let performanceTabItem = UITabBarItem(title: "example", image: "tabImage", selectedImage: "selectedTabImage" )
```

5.set

```
exampleVC.tabBarItem = performanceTabItem
```

6.append exampleVC with viewControllers

```
viewControllers.append(exampleVC)
```

7.set viewControllers of UITabBarController.

```
tabController.viewControllers = viewControllers
```

Comment: Where do you get the UITabBarController? In the AppDelegate? In a ViewController that is a Tab of the UITabBar? Somewhere else?

Comment: you can have a custom class of TabBarController and set it in Storyboard.